# Record Is Deleted message in Microsoft Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

In a Microsoft Access Application I'm modifying, certain vba functions return the message:

```
"Record is Deleted"
```

This appears in a message box with no error number and a yellow caution icon.

This is not a error that can be trapped by traditional error handling ("on error...".  It is also not affected by DoCmd.setwarnings=false

I'm looking for some advice on how to trap or handle this item.

Answer (score 2):

"Record is deleted" is run-time error 3167 and it can be trapped using normal `On Error` handling. This can be verified via VBA code like the following:

```vbs
Sub foo()
Dim cdb As DAO.Database, rst As DAO.Recordset
Set cdb = CurrentDb
Set rst = cdb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ID=26", dbOpenDynaset)
MsgBox "Waiting..."
On Error GoTo foo_Error
Debug.Print rst!ID
On Error GoTo 0
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set cdb = Nothing
Exit Sub
foo_Error:
MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbOKOnly, "Trapped Error"
End Sub
```

If you run that code and then "delete the record out from under it" while the `MsgBox` is displayed then the `rst!` reference in the `Debug.Print` triggers the run-time error 3167 and the `On Error` catches it.

Check your code to see if there is an active `On Error` (possibly declared in an earlier calling procedure) that simply displays a plain `MsgBox` with the `Err.Description`. That would explain the behaviour you describe.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you pull a record to delete from multiple tables... such as

```
sql = "SELECT columnA FROM tableA WHERE criteria"
set rec = currentdb.openrecordset(sql)

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE FROM tableA WHERE columnA = " & rec(0)
    DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE FROM tableB WHERE columnB = " & rec(0)
    DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE FROM tableC WHERE columnC = " & rec(0)
    DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE tableD SET status WHERE columnD = " & rec(0)
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

This will fail on the second Delete line because rec(0) no longer exists on the second line, you just deleted it from tableA which is where your recordset comes from.

However,

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE FROM tableB WHERE columnB = " & rec(0)
    DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE FROM tableC WHERE columnC = " & rec(0)
    DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE tableD SET status WHERE columnD = " & rec(0)
    DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE FROM tableA WHERE columnA = " & rec(0)
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

will work.  It may not be the best practice method, but if you have this error, try this to see if the recordset being deleted is the reason.

A better method might be to declare a variable and assign rec(0).value to that variable.  Then use the variable in place of rec(0) in the code.